# Is the "Mosul Sniper" a real individual or a propaganda stunt by US and its allies?

Tags: isis

I'm reading various news reports such as [this](http://nypost.com/2016/10/24/the-sniper-of-mosul-is-picking-off-jihadis-one-by-one/) and [this](http://www.foxnews.com/world/2016/10/25/sniper-mosul-strikes-fear-in-hearts-isis-fighters.html) about a mysterious sniper that kill ISIS militia and executioners.

These reports seem to me a bit out of the blue.

For example the last article I read was about a executioner being killed just before he was going to behead a teenager.

[Article Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3871454/The-Sniper-Mosul-strikes-Marksman-takes-ISIS-executioner-just-moments-behead-Iraqi-teenager.html)

I believe that this "one man army" could be made-up? There are several versions of these articles which contains information that could only be given by the gunman, but they don't know his identity.

Could this gunman be the modern **Vasily Zaytsev** or just a myth to rally people against ISIS?

[Wikipedia page about Vasily Zaytsev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Zaytsev)

Comment: It's probably quite difficult to do good fact checking in Mosul right now... Most articles qualify the story with "Reports from Iraq say..." and "A sniper, or group of snipers" - it'll be at least a week or so before there's any evidence

Comment: This is my first question in the skeptics stackexchange. Is it a general requirement to be able to verify if my skepticism about the realness of "Mosul Sniper" is grounded? I just wanted to do a check if more people had the same feeling over this subject, I was not looking for real proof.

Comment: Yeah, this site is definitely about hard proof only, not people's gut feelings.

Comment: I would argue that part of the point of the site is to get hard proof on questions like this. I'm voting to reopen.